# Number One Ecch Magazine

Tags: word-meaning

From an [article](https://www.thedailybeast.com/mad-magazine-taught-us-to-laugh-but-now-we-laugh-at-it?ref=scroll) of the Daily Beast about the MAD Magazine:

> FURSHLUGGINER! POTRZEBIE! GANEFS! MAD is KAPUTNIK!
>
> Okay, maybe not quite. Physically and editorially speaking, the
>   self-proclaimed “Number One **Ecch** Magazine” still exists.

What does "ecch" mean here? I could find a [definition](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ecch) in the Urban Dictionary, but don't know if it fits here. (I am aware of the many neologisms created by the MAD Magazine; I used to be a reader of the German edition after all.)

Comment: [Mad Magazine **Ecch! Rated** Super Special # 135 March 1999 Issue!](https://www.amazon.com/Magazine-Rated-Super-Special-March/dp/B0032QYVPY) That one's punning ***Ecch*** with ***X-rated*** - but back in the 60s, where it appeared as an exclamation within the cartoons themselves, I always read it as a quirky American way of writing ***Yuck!*** or ***Ugh!*** (different orthographies for the same expression of disgust).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think it's meant to be the sound of disgust, like *retching*, but as far as I know it's only in common use in MAD Magazine.

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed. I'm familiar enough with [*Ach!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ach+snorted%22) (though it always looks a bit Scottish / Germanic to me). But *Ecch!* (along with *Potrzebie* and several others) has no associations apart from being in Mad's lexicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A colorful term to describe some thing disgusting". That's the right meaning. It's usually said by someone about someone or something else. MAD was famous for saying it about themselves, possibly because they knew that other people were going to say that they had a "disgusting" sense of humour (even though a lot of the humour in it was, in fact less disgusting than it might have been).

Comment: It’s maybe worth noting that this could be regarded as [*self-deprecating humor*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SelfDeprecation).

Comment: MAD used to be more on the edge back in its day, but with the kind of comedic "shock jockeys" now common, its humor has become tame.